# Running SSH commands on multiple servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

At the company I work at, we have no real way to quickly execute shell commands on all of our customers systems, which often results in what we call `Tiny Tim` tasks, where the list of all of our systems is split between the 5 devs we have, and we simply go through one-by-one, SSHing into each one and executing the necessary commands.

To streamline this process, I created a script in Python3 using Paramiko for SSH.
The script takes the path to a private OpenSSH key from command-line args, reads a list of hosts from a file called `hosts.txt` (lines in this file can be commented by prepending them with `--`), and a list of shell commands from a file called `cmds.txt`. Due to the way we set up our customers' systems, each domain has 2 servers, so the script loops over each host in the list twice, prepending `disc1.` and `disc2.` respectively to send the commands to both servers.

```py
from paramiko.client import AutoAddPolicy
from paramiko.client import SSHClient
import sys
from sys import argv

if len(argv) < 2:
    print("Invalid args!")
    print("Usage: python3 run.py <private ssh key filepath>")
    exit()

with open('cmds.txt') as c:
    cmds = c.readlines()

with open('hosts.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    for i in range(1, 3):
        line = line.strip()
        host = "disc%s.%s" % (i, line)
        if line.startswith('--'):
            print("Host %s began with --, skipping" % line)
            continue
        client = SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        try:
            print("[%s]> Connecting as root on port 22..." % host)
            client.connect(host, 22, 'root', None, None, argv[1])
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except Exception as err:
            print("[%s]> Connection failed: %s" % (host, err))
            continue
        for c in cmds:
            print("[%s]> Executing %s..." % (host, c.strip()))
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(c)
            print(stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
            print(stderr.read().decode('utf-8'))
        client.close()
        print("[%s]> Done" % host)
```

I ran it through [PEP8](http://pep8online.com/) and surprisingly didn't get any errors or warnings, but it's still quite messy and I'd appreciate feedback.

Comment: When I've recently had to do something like this, I used `pxssh` from [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  It makes such tasks much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/tutorial.html) is what you need.

Fabric is a pretty simple deploy tool (comparing to Ansible/Puppet/etc), that lets you execute simple shell commands over SSH (Paramiko inside).

Features you will get from it:

1. You can specify SSH key path using command line:

   ```
   fab command -i /path/to/key.pem
   ```

   or parse it from command line:

   ```
   import sys
   from fabric.api import *
   ...
   env.key_filename = sys.argv[2] or '/path/to/keyfile.pem'
   ```
2. Describe local/remote tasks in pythonic way:
       from fabric.api import *

   ```
   def local_test():
       local('nosetests .')

   def remote_pull():
       run('git pull')
   ```

   And chain/group/do-anything-you want to them.
3. You can describe host list:

   ```
   hosts = [<your_hosts_list>]
   env.hosts = ['disc{}.{}'.format(host, index) for host in hosts for index in xrange(1,3)]
   ```

   or you can describe roles:

   ```
   env.roledefs['group1'] = ['host.name.com']
   env.roledefs['group2'] = ['host1.name.com', 'host2.name.com']
   ```

   and use this roles/hosts in your tasks configuration then:

   ```
   @roles('group1')
   @runs_once
   def add_tag(version):
       run('git tag -f {}'.format(version))
   ```

And many more features out of the box!

Comment: For strict code review I like the answer that @alecxe provided, but for solving the problem as presented I would agree that fabric is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Overall, the code is not complicated and can be understood. I would though focus on improving variable names and modularity:

- remember that the code is much more often read than written - try to name your variables in a meaningful way:

  - `for line in lines` should be `for host in hosts`
  - `for i in range(1, 3)` can be `for customer_index in range(1, 3)`
  - `cmds` may be renamed to a more explicit `commands`
  - `c` should probably be `command`
- I would apply the ["Extract Method" refactoring method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to move all SSH client related logic to a separate function

Other notes:

- `SSHClient` can be used as a *context manager*
- remove unused `import sys` import
- organize import as per [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)
- put your main execution logic to under [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid the code to be executed on import

Improved code:

```
from sys import argv

from paramiko.client import AutoAddPolicy
from paramiko.client import SSHClient
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException


def apply_commands(host, commands):
    with SSHClient() as client:
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
        client.load_system_host_keys()

        print("[%s]> Connecting as root on port 22..." % host)
        client.connect(host, 22, 'root', None, None, argv[1])

        for command in commands:
            print("[%s]> Executing %s..." % (host, command.strip()))

            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)

            print(stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
            print(stderr.read().decode('utf-8'))

    print("[%s]> Done" % host)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print("Invalid args!")
        print("Usage: python3 run.py <private ssh key filepath>")
        exit()

    with open('cmds.txt') as f:
        commands = f.readlines()

    with open('hosts.txt') as f:
        hosts = f.readlines()

    for host in hosts:
        for customer_index in range(1, 3):
            host = host.strip()
            host = "disc%s.%s" % (customer_index, host)

            if host.startswith('--'):
                print("Host %s began with --, skipping" % host)
                continue

            try:
                apply_commands(host, commands)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
            except SSHException as err:
                print("[%s]> SSH Error: %s" % (host, err))
                continue
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I noticed you also switched the `except Exception` for `except SSHException`, which definitely makes more sense. I'm not sure `if __name__ == '__main__':` is needed though, as the script should never be imported by any other scripts.

Comment: @Mayube yup, it is not really a big deal at all - just a best practice. Thanks.